# Cannot run a simple Hello World program using nodejs

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

After downloading `Node.js` and `Visual Studio Code` and after setting up the folders and changing it into respective directories using command lines inside the integrated `powershell` of `VS Code`, the 'node app.js' command fails to run the *Hello World* program. I wrote 'node' along with the full name of the directory and the filename `app.js`, still its unable to run it.
I have attached the screenshot of it.

[image]

Comment: You have two good answers. Please do not forget to mark the answer that helped you as "accepted".

Comment: duplicate of [Why don't other programs see the changes I made to a file in VS Code until I save those changes?](/q/76984829/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you haven't saved your file. Save it and try to execute it again.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to save your file, In `VSCode` - a white dot next to the file indicates unsaved changes to the file.
Save your file `Ctrl+S` and fire off `node app.js` like that :

[image]

Comment: @AnkanChanda You're welcome ! Now you can accept this answer as it solved your problem ! ;-)